# Oracle - WHERE COM SYSDATE

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

No primeiro select o SALDO está vindo zerado, no segundo que substituo o sysdate por qual seria a data ele traz o valor correto

qual deve ser o problema no sysdate+4 no where?

```
SELECT SYSDATE+4 DATA, (SELECT NVL(SUM(E1_SALDO),0) A 
FROM PROTHEUS.SE1010
INNER JOIN PROTHEUS.SED010 ON ED_CODIGO=E1_NATUREZ
WHERE SE1010.D_E_L_E_T_<>'*' AND SED010.D_E_L_E_T_<>'*' AND E1_SALDO<>'0' AND (TO_DATE(E1_VENCREA, 'YYYYMMDD')) = (SYSDATE+4))A
FROM DUAL

SELECT SYSDATE+4 DATA, (SELECT NVL(SUM(E1_SALDO),0) A 
FROM PROTHEUS.SE1010
INNER JOIN PROTHEUS.SED010 ON ED_CODIGO=E1_NATUREZ
WHERE SE1010.D_E_L_E_T_<>'*' AND SED010.D_E_L_E_T_<>'*' AND E1_SALDO<>'0' AND E1_VENCREA = ('20190924'))A
FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O retorno do `SYSDATE` depende de como está configurado o `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`, o formato deve estar diferente e a comparação está falhando.

Veja um exemplo abaixo:

```
SELECT 
SYSDATE DATA1, --o retorno aqui depende do NLS_DATE_FORMAT que provavelmente retorna diferente do que está esperando 'YYYYMMDD'
TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDD') DATA2 --Aqui estou convertendo essa data no formato que deseja, mas como char
FROM DUAL;
```

Abaixo fiz mais um exemplo comparando algumas datas:

```
SELECT 
     CASE TO_CHAR(DATA1, 'YYYYMMDD') WHEN DATA2 THEN 'V'
     ELSE 'F' END COMPARA_1_2,
     CASE TO_CHAR(DATA3, 'YYYYMMDD') WHEN DATA4 THEN 'V'
     ELSE 'F' END COMPARA_3_4
 FROM
  (SELECT 
  SYSDATE DATA1, 
  TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDD') DATA2,
  SYSDATE DATA3, 
  TO_CHAR(SYSDATE+4, 'YYYYMMDD') DATA4
  FROM DUAL) QRY;
```

Na sua query ficaria assim:

```
SELECT SYSDATE+4 DATA, (SELECT NVL(SUM(E1_SALDO),0) A 
FROM PROTHEUS.SE1010
INNER JOIN PROTHEUS.SED010 ON ED_CODIGO=E1_NATUREZ
WHERE SE1010.D_E_L_E_T_<>'*' AND SED010.D_E_L_E_T_<>'*' AND E1_SALDO<>'0' AND (TO_CHAR(E1_VENCREA, 'YYYYMMDD')) = (TO_CHAR(SYSDATE+4, 'YYYYMMDD')))A
FROM DUAL
```

Comment: Ou TO_DATE(E1_VENCREA, 'YYYYMMDD') = Trunc(SYSDATE+4)

Comment: George, assim deu erro ORA-01481..
 Segui sua lógica e consegui assim:

 AND (TO_DATE(E1_VENCREA,'YYYYMMDD')) = (TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE+4, 'YYYYMMDD'),'YYYYMMDD')))A

Como Motta sugeriu funcionou também

Muito obrigado senhores!!

Comment: Acho que mataria o cara da Totvs que decidiu usar string no lugar de date .... :)